# ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32,128,240,240] and type float on Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, tf.keras

I'm using [Google Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/) to the following U-NET network:

```
def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = (240, 240, 1)):
    inputs = Input(input_size)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv5)
    drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    up6 = Conv2D(512, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(drop5))
    merge6 = concatenate([drop4,up6], axis = 3)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv6)

    up7 = Conv2D(256, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv6))
    merge7 = concatenate([conv3,up7], axis = 3)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv7)

    up8 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv7))
    merge8 = concatenate([conv2,up8], axis = 3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv8)

    up9 = Conv2D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv8))
    merge9 = concatenate([conv1,up9], axis = 3)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(2, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = conv10)

    model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

    #model.summary()

    if(pretrained_weights):
        model.load_weights(pretrained_weights)

    return model
```

With this summary:

> ```
> <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training.Model'>
> Model: "model"
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
> ==================================================================================================
> input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 240, 240, 1) 0                                            
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d (Conv2D)                 (None, 240, 240, 64) 640         input_1[0][0]                    
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 240, 240, 64) 36928       conv2d[0][0]                     
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 120, 120, 64) 0           conv2d_1[0][0]                   
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 120, 120, 128 73856       max_pooling2d[0][0]              
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, 120, 120, 128 147584      conv2d_2[0][0]                   
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 60, 60, 128)  0           conv2d_3[0][0]                   
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_4 (Conv2D)               (None, 60, 60, 256)  295168      max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_5 (Conv2D)               (None, 60, 60, 256)  590080      conv2d_4[0][0]                   
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 30, 30, 256)  0           conv2d_5[0][0]                   
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_6 (Conv2D)               (None, 30, 30, 512)  1180160     max_pooling2d_2[0][0]            
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_7 (Conv2D)               (None, 30, 30, 512)  2359808     conv2d_6[0][0]                   
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> dropout (Dropout)               (None, 30, 30, 512)  0           conv2d_7[0][0]                   
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 15, 15, 512)  0           dropout[0][0]                    
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_8 (Conv2D)               (None, 15, 15, 1024) 4719616     max_pooling2d_3[0][0]            
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_9 (Conv2D)               (None, 15, 15, 1024) 9438208     conv2d_8[0][0]                   
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 15, 15, 1024) 0           conv2d_9[0][0]                   
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> up_sampling2d (UpSampling2D)    (None, 30, 30, 1024) 0           dropout_1[0][0]                  
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_10 (Conv2D)              (None, 30, 30, 512)  2097664     up_sampling2d[0][0]              
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 30, 30, 1024) 0           dropout[0][0]                    
>                                                                  conv2d_10[0][0]                  
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_11 (Conv2D)              (None, 30, 30, 512)  4719104     concatenate[0][0]                
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_12 (Conv2D)              (None, 30, 30, 512)  2359808     conv2d_11[0][0]                  
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 60, 60, 512)  0           conv2d_12[0][0]                  
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_13 (Conv2D)              (None, 60, 60, 256)  524544      up_sampling2d_1[0][0]            
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 60, 60, 512)  0           conv2d_5[0][0]                   
>                                                                  conv2d_13[0][0]                  
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_14 (Conv2D)              (None, 60, 60, 256)  1179904     concatenate_1[0][0]              
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_15 (Conv2D)              (None, 60, 60, 256)  590080      conv2d_14[0][0]                  
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 120, 120, 256 0           conv2d_15[0][0]                  
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_16 (Conv2D)              (None, 120, 120, 128 131200      up_sampling2d_2[0][0]            
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> concatenate_2 (Concatenate)     (None, 120, 120, 256 0           conv2d_3[0][0]                   
>                                                                  conv2d_16[0][0]                  
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_17 (Conv2D)              (None, 120, 120, 128 295040      concatenate_2[0][0]              
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_18 (Conv2D)              (None, 120, 120, 128 147584      conv2d_17[0][0]                  
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> up_sampling2d_3 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 240, 240, 128 0           conv2d_18[0][0]                  
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_19 (Conv2D)              (None, 240, 240, 64) 32832       up_sampling2d_3[0][0]            
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> concatenate_3 (Concatenate)     (None, 240, 240, 128 0           conv2d_1[0][0]                   
>                                                                  conv2d_19[0][0]                  
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_20 (Conv2D)              (None, 240, 240, 64) 73792       concatenate_3[0][0]              
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_21 (Conv2D)              (None, 240, 240, 64) 36928       conv2d_20[0][0]                  
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_22 (Conv2D)              (None, 240, 240, 2)  1154        conv2d_21[0][0]                  
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_23 (Conv2D)              (None, 240, 240, 1)  3           conv2d_22[0][0]                  
> ==================================================================================================
> Total params: 31,031,685
> Trainable params: 31,031,685
> Non-trainable params: 0
> ```

When I train this network with the following code:

I get this error:

```
Train on 864 samples, validate on 96 samples
Epoch 1/5
 32/864 [>.............................] - ETA: 4:20

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-12-bed1e9ed5833> in <module>()
      3 
      4 results = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=5,
----> 5                     validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid))
      6 

11 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32,128,240,240] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node Conv2DBackpropFilter_4-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
 [Op:__inference_distributed_function_3113]

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

Any suggestion to improve my network? Maybe this is because I'm using images with float pixels, and values between 0.0 and 1684.0.

Another option is Google Colaboratory is full at this moment. I have tried five times, and I get four times this error and only on run successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that you run out of memory while training the neural network, it is not related to the float value of the pixels.

The solution is to gradually reduce the `batch_size` parameter.

If you pay attention here:

```
 results = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=5,
                   validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid))
```

you will see that the default `batch_size` is 32.

Reduce it to 16. If it still does not work and throws OOM errors, reduce it to 8; do this(reduce with a factor of 2) until there are no more OOM errors.

Comment: It may happen that the only solution is making the model smaller too...

Comment: Correct; otoh I think that Colab available video cards are able to handle a batch size of 2/4 for a size of 240x240x1.